# Why is down vote on question not -1?

Tags: discussion, support, down-votes

Down voting a question gives -2 rep to the asker, but up voting gives +5.

Since the up votes are halved on questions, why the down votes are not halved as well? Specially since they gives no penalty to the down voter.

Comment: Why should it be proportional?

Comment: @Bill I can see some logic there. If questions aren't important enough to award +10 per upvote, are they important enough to have the same penalty per downvote as answers?

Comment: @Anna: See my answer for my interpretation of the (somewhat arbitrary) numbers.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Should a down vote on an answer be worth -4?](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/93359/should-a-down-vote-on-an-answer-be-worth-4)

Comment: @Code not really. He is asking -4 for answers

Answer (score 12, accepted):

You're talking about two different things.  The +5 for a question upvote is a *reward* for asking a good question, but the -2 for a downvote is a *penalty* for asking a bad one.  We want to [encourage good answers more than good questions](https://blog.stackoverflow.com/2010/03/important-reputation-rule-changes/), so answer upvotes are worth more.  But we want to *discourage bad questions* just as much, so the penalty for downvotes are the same.

Comment: Technically speaking, aren't bad questions discouraged *more* than bad answers, since there is no penalty on the person casting the downvote?

Comment: Small problem with that is answers can be deleted, while questions can't (under certain circumstances), therefore the penalty for bad question can be severe.

Comment: @Chris: It depends on how you look at it.  People are more likely to use downvotes on questions, so they may be discouraged *more often*, but for each downvote they're discouraged by the *same amount*.  Yet another way to look at it is proportionally (10/2 vs. 5/2), which gives you a stiffer penalty on question downvotes.  On the whole, I'd say yes, technically bad questions are discouraged *more* than bad answers.  I think that's okay though, since downvoted answers sink to the bottom of the page, while bad questions do not.

Comment: @VJo: I don't see that as a problem.  You can either edit a bad question to make it better (if it has a good answer, for example) or flag it for a moderator to delete.